# Xamarin Unsupported Libraries/Features

Tags: xamarin

I'm a web developer and I stumbled upon Xamarin. What caught my interest is the building of "Cross Platform Applications".
It's pretty amazing that it could do that.
I've read Xamarin's site about the libraries that it supports (Android & iOS).

Are there any libraries/features that Xamarin lack?

Any idea/s will really help!

Comment: A good description given here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604021/pros-and-cons-of-xamarin-vis-a-vis-other-frameworks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if i understand the question completly. But if your question is if you have any cons against a native development of that plattform. Then no.

Anything which is possible in Anroid/iOS Development is possible within Xamarin.

Comment: The last part of your comment is what I'm looking for. Now I need to dig deep about it.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say there are no cons against native development. All technologies have pros and cons, Xamarin and native included.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that stands out to me as something that could be harder in Xamarin than in Native is if you are using third party controls or libraries that don't already have a Xamarin binding. In order to call these from Xamarin you will need to create your own bindings (a wrapper around the library that lets Xamarin call into it). There are tools to help with this, but it's generally a tedious process. As more third party vendors add Xamarin support to their libraries this becomes less of a concern.